# Is it possible to compile multiple dependent C files, without creating header file?

Tags: c, compilation

I am having some issues with putting multiple .c files together.
I will mimic my situation with the following files.

**mod.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
void print_hello() {
  printf("Hello!");
}
```

**mod_main.c**

```
#include "mod.c"
int main() {
  print_hello();
}
```

**Compiling scenarios:**

**#1**

```
$ cc -o mod_main mod_main.c
# No errors
```

**#2**

```
$ cc -c -o mod_main.o mod_main.c
$ cc -c -o mod.o mod.c
$ cc -o mod_main mod.o mod_main.o
duplicate symbol '_print_hello' in:
    mod.o
    mod_main.o
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture x86_64
```

**#3**

```
$ cc -o mod_main mod.c mod_main.c
duplicate symbol '_print_hello' in:
```

Based on these attempts, I gather that, I can compile simply `mod_main.c` & get it working. Or, I can create a `.h` file as follows & get it working.

**mod.h**

```
void print_hello(void);
```

**mod.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mod.h"
void print_hello() {
  printf("Hello!");
}
```

**mod_main.c**

```
#include "mod.h"
int main() {
  print_hello();
}
```

I like to know, if there are any other ways to compile multiple C files that has dependencies within each other. To be precise, is there a decent way to avoid writing header files?

Good day!

PS: I have explored similar questions on StackOverflow. None of them that I could find where asking the exact questions as mine.

Comment: Define the function as `extern` in `main` if you don't want to have `.h` file.

Comment: Including source files is generally a bad idea. If you want to avoid header files (why? What is the problem that is supposed to solve?) then write the declarations you normally have in the header file inside the source files themselves, copy-paste as needed. Note that this will be error-prone if you have many source files, for example if you modify a function signature in all but one source file that will lead to *undefined behavior* (copy-paste programming is generally frowned upon). In short: Use header files!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, no specific reason to avoid header files. Simply wanted to know if there is an another way to do the same, that I haven't learned yet. Thanks for your advice. I will use header files only.

Comment: One disadvantage of using the `extern` approach in one source file is that if you ever change the signature of the real code in the `.c` file but forget to change the matching `extern`, you're going to have problems that are difficult to solve.  By always having the declaration in the header file collide with the actual definition in the source file, you'll catch these kinds of mistakes.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I consider that an answer. Even one which I'd like to point at from dupliates. Please make one. Or propose an existing duplicate.

Comment: @Yunnosch Perhaps something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62749369/440558)? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, including source files is generally a bad idea.

As for the problem itself, you can easily solve it by pretending you're writing a header file, but instead write all declarations, structure definitions and macros in a source file. Then copy-paste it into the other source files who needs it.

But, and this is a very important but, this is extremely error-prone. If the signature (e.g. argument list) of a function changes, or a structure is modified, or a macro gets a different value, then you must remember to modify this *everywhere*. If you have more than a couple of source files it becomes easy to miss one of the files.

If a function with the wrong signature is called, or you have structures that are not character-by-character copies of each other, then that will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). Mismatching macros *might* not be so serious, but if it's an array-limit that is changed (for example) then it's easy to go out of bounds where you miss to update the macro.

In short: It's possible, but not a good idea. Use one or more header files for common declarations, structures and macros.